# Listen to element - call function when another element is appended to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, typeahead.js

### Intro

I have a search bar I implemented into my website which searches through member cards to find matching cards. I also used Twitter's typeahead.js for this. The results are updated **as you type**, so I set an event listener on the input box - `$('#members-search .typeahead').on("input", changeFunction);` I also needed to set a click event listener on the suggestions, as I did - `$('.tt-suggestion').on("click", changeFunction);`

---

### Problem

It seems like the suggestion boxes are created on the fly, so you can't set an event listener for all (or even any!) of them at the beginning. My first idea was to fire a function when an element was appended in the containing div. However, you would need an event listener for that, and I couldn't find one. Is there any way to implement this?

---

### Code

The JavaScript:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var children = document.getElementById("members-list").children;
var names = [];
var whoIsWho = [];
var selected = [];
var listOfAttributeNames = ["data-member-name", "data-member-username", "data-member-nickname"];
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < listOfAttributeNames.length; j++){
        var a;
        if(a = children[i].getAttribute(listOfAttributeNames[j])){
            names.push(a);
            whoIsWho.push(children[i]);
        }
    }
}
$('#members-search .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'names',
  source: substringMatcher(names)
});
var previousValue = "";
function changeFunction(e){
    var v;
    if($("#members-search .typeahead").val() === ""){
        previousValue = "";
    }
    else if(((v = $('#members-search .typeahead+pre').text())) !== previousValue){
        previousValue = v;
    }
    else if(v !== $("#members-search .typeahead").val()){
        previousValue = $("#members-search .typeahead").val();
    }
    selected = [];
    v = $('#members-search .typeahead+pre').text();
    for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){;
        if(!(new RegExp(v, "i").test(names[i])) && !(selected.includes(whoIsWho[i]))){
            whoIsWho[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        else{
            selected.push(whoIsWho[i]);
            whoIsWho[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
$('#members-search .typeahead').on("input", changeFunction);
$('.tt-suggestion').on("click", changeFunction);
```

The (important) HTML:

```
<div id="members-search">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

---

### Alternate, Backup Solutions

I could copy the bloodhound script over to my code and modify where the elements are appended, but I'd rather not, as it uses this weird format of IIFE that I won't take the time to understand. Or is there another solution and this question is part of the X/Y problem?

Comment: Any reason you can't listen for `"click"` events on the element that contains the suggestions? (You don't really show your markup, so it's hard to be more specific.)

Comment: This is because the suggestion elements are created when you type, and you can't add an event listener to a nonexistent (or not created) element.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the wrong approach. I just added an event listener to the current suggestions every time the input value was changed.

```
$('#members-search .typeahead').on("input", function(){
    $('.tt-suggestion').on("click", changeFunction);
});
```